# Override typescript enum descriptions

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following enum generated somewhere outside of my app:

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED",
    Green = "GREEN",
    Blue = "BLUE",
}
```

This enum is used as a type for generated interface property

```
interface MyObject {
  objectName: string,
  objectColor: Colors
}
```

Is it possible to override enum string values so that same enum value could have new descriptions like this:

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED car",
    Green = "GREEN grass",
    Blue = "BLUE sky",
}
```

Comment: Is using the enum beside with a statically-functioned `namespace` not an option for your case like mentioned in the last section of this page:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html
Or you have to override the enum?

Comment: It is an option, just looking for a cleaner solution where I'll be able to use property directly in the template and rely on angular built in enum value to description mapping rather than custom function call for every entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this, I would caution against doing it, if you don't do it early some variables might get stuck with the old values and create problems:

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED",
    Green = "GREEN",
    Blue = "BLUE",
}
console.log(Colors.Red);
let red = Colors.Red;

(Colors as any)['Red'] = "Dark Red" // Force the enum to any and change the internal value.

console.log(Colors.Red);
console.log(red === Colors.Red); // false, because red got the old value
```

At runtime the `enum` is just a Javascript object that contains the `enum` fields with the specified values, so changing it is not a problem:

```
var Colors;
(function (Colors) {
    Colors["Red"] = "RED";
    Colors["Green"] = "GREEN";
    Colors["Blue"] = "BLUE";
})(Colors || (Colors = {}));
```